# economics paper with most coauthors

Tags: reference-request

A high number of co-authors on scientific papers is not uncommon, but in economics I rarely see one with more than 5 coauthors.

Does anyone know the paper in economics that has the **highest number of co-authors** (whether wp or journal article)?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. For example, you could have at least show us quick look at some attempt to search in google scholar/econlit

Answer (score 4):

Economists also publish in Science or Nature sometimes, and if the study is interdisciplinary, there could involve many co-authors just like other scientific papers.

In the prestigious economic journals, the economics paper with most coauthors is Benjamin, Daniel J., et al. "The Promises and Pitfalls of Genoeconomics." Annu. Rev. Econ. 4.1 (2012): 627-662.  or Coenen, Günter, et al. "Effects of fiscal stimulus in structural models." American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics 4.1 (2012): 22-68.

Comment: With 22 and 17 authors, respectively.